# i have multiple users on multiple servers but for example lets say user1 and user2 which exist on server1 and server2 i need ssh-keys using ansible

Tags: ansible

Users

- user1
- user2

Hosts

- server1
- server2

Requirements:

1. In order for ssh-keys to work, i want user1.server1.public_key to be appeneded to user1.server2.authorized_keys but i also need user1.server2.public_key to be appended to user1.server1.authorized_keys.
2. I need point 1 to be implemented for user2 as well.

Outcome: every server for every user will have 2 keys under authorized_keys

Below code helps me append user1.server1.public_key to user1.server1.authorized_keys
but does not help me append the same key to **user1.server2.authorized_keys**

```yaml
---
- name: Generate SSH Keys and Append to Authorized Keys
  hosts: server2 
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    users:
      - user1
      - user2
  tasks:
    - name: Set backup timestamp
      set_fact:
        backup_timestamp: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%d%m%Y_%H%M%S') }}"
    - name: Backup existing .ssh directory
      command: mv "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh" "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh_bkp_{{ backup_timestamp }}"
      become_user: root
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      ignore_errors: yes  # Ignore errors if .ssh directory doesn't exist
    - name: Ensure .ssh directory
      file:
        path: "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh"
        state: directory
        owner: "{{ item }}"
        group: users
        mode: '0700'
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      become_user: root

    - name: Generate SSH Key Pair for User
      command: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh/id_rsa" -N ""
      args:
        creates: "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh/id_rsa"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      become_user: "{{ item }}"

    - name: Wait for Key Files to Be Generated
      wait_for:
        path: "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh/id_rsa"
      loop: "{{ users }}"

    - name: Ensure authorized_keys file exists
      file:
        path: "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        state: touch
        mode: '0600'
        owner: "{{ item }}"
        group: users
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      become_user: root

    - name: Fetch id_rsa.pub
      fetch:
        src: "/home/{{ item }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
        dest: "/tmp/id_rsa_pub_{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      become_user: root
    - name: Append Public Key to Authorized Keys
      shell: "cat /home/{{ item }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/{{ item }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      become_user: "{{ item }}"
```